# SQL Paramter parse bug

Tags: java, sql

I've encountered with a "bug/feature" with SQL (org.httprpc.sql) parse.

If the sql column name contains `:` then its confuse the parser and got error.

eg: `select 1 as "this is:notparam"`

> The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.

Is there any workaround to fix this issue? I can't really avoid `:` at names, cause there are a lot of user definied queries and dynamic Excels as paramters.

Code:

```
    String sql = reportTab.getSqlStatement();

    // Parse SQL paramters
    Parameters parameters = Parameters.parse(sql);
    // Get connection from pool
    Connection connection = getConnectionWithStatus(task,ds);

    task.setExecutionStartTime(LocalDateTime.now());

    task.setConnection(connection);
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    List<List<Object>> resultSet = new LinkedList<>();

    try {

        statement = connection.prepareStatement(parameters.getSQL());
        parameters.apply(statement, paramMap);
        task.setPreparedStatement(statement);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        List<Object> columnNames = getColumnNames(rs);
        long rowCount = 0;
        task.setCurrentResultSetIndex(rowCount);
        while (rs.next()) {
```

Maven dependencies:

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>2.5.4</version> -->
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</parent>
```

JDBC drivers (all of them has the same symptom)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Full stacktrace:

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setNull(PgPreparedStatement.java:197)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setObject(PgPreparedStatement.java:948)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setObject(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.httprpc.sql.Parameters.apply(Parameters.java:66)
        at com.happy.python.application.service.data.CJdbcService.executeReportTask(CJdbcService.java:96)
        at com.happy.python.application.service.data.CJdbcService.executeReportTask(CJdbcService.java:55)
        at com.happy.python.application.data.entity.report.task.ReportTask.extractAndExecuteSingeReportTab(ReportTask.java:436)
        at com.happy.python.application.data.entity.report.task.ReportTask.run(ReportTask.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
java.sql.SQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.
        at com.happy.python.application.service.data.CJdbcService.executeReportTask(CJdbcService.java:148)
        at com.happy.python.application.service.data.CJdbcService.executeReportTask(CJdbcService.java:55)
        at com.happy.python.application.data.entity.report.task.ReportTask.extractAndExecuteSingeReportTab(ReportTask.java:436)
        at com.happy.python.application.data.entity.report.task.ReportTask.run(ReportTask.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: Please specify the DBMS you're using, and provide a [mre], including the full exception stacktrace. Also, if you think you found a bug in a library, you should report it to the project that created that library.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to replace ':' with '::'

Comment: its only hide the problem, eg: it also break if there I use regex in the sql... I can't use double :: there, cause its break the regex tho.